# After entering text in outlined input it is displaying as capital letters

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have an MUI outlined input, when I enter any text in the input it is always showing me capital letters(shown in image) instead original letters, can any one help me with that.

[image]

my code:

```
 <FormControl fullWidth variant='outlined'>
    <InputLabel htmlFor='new-password'>New Password</InputLabel>
    <OutlinedInput
      id='new-password'
      className='marginBtm15px'
      value={newPassword}
      label='New Password'
      type={showPassword ? 'text' : 'password'}
      onChange={handleNewPasswordChange}
      endAdornment={
        <InputAdornment position='end'>
          <IconButton onClick={handleClickShowPassword} onMouseDown={handleMouseDownPassword}>
            {showPassword ? <p className='showHide'>Hide</p> : <p className='showHide'>Show</p>}
          </IconButton>
        </InputAdornment>
      }
      autoCapitalize='off'
    />
  </FormControl>
```

CSS:

```
.marginBtm15px {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
 }
```

Comment: Please check your global css or material ui theme, where you can override the css property, otherwise, this will not happened usually.

Answer (score 0):

Can you also share Css of class "marginBtm15px".
Try using browser inspect element feature to detect from where textTransform property coming.

Comment: updated question with CSS